Can paths be specified before other parameters in git log?
I want to create a git alias where the <path> part is part of the alias, but where I can still pass additional parameters.
Currently these are relevant aliases in my git config:
[alias]
  lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --abbrev=8
  lolst = "!git lol --name-status $(git diff --staged --name-only | tr '\\n' ' ')"
  # Simpler version just for this Q/A.
  logst = "!git log $(git diff --staged --name-only | tr '\\n' ' ')"

The purpose of lolst and logst is to show a history of all staged files. It actually works as intended.
Now I want to be able to add additional parameters with these commands.
E.g. git lolst -U3 to show a diff with each commit.
However, this gives me "fatal: option '-U3' must come before non-option argument".
It is obvious why this happens: The file list must come after the arguments.
How could I create the alias so that I can add additional parameters after?
Bonus info - why I want these commits
Once I have the commit ids, I can do git commit --fixup=<commit id>. Then git rebase -ir --autosquash <some ancestor ref>. I also created aliases for these, but they are out of scope for this Q/A.

xargs should be able to help here.
Since the file names go last in git log, the following should work:
[alias]
logst = "!git diff --staged --name-only | xargs git log"

We can now add  other git log options. For example:
git logst --pretty=online -n 10


Just be aware that if the number of staged files is massive (or file names are very long), then xargs will run git log more than once.

perhaps relevant to the OP: xargs also has the -r | --no-run-if-empty option, to avoid running git log altogether if you have no staged diff.

lolst = "!f() { git lol --name-status \"$@\" -- $(git diff --staged --name-only); }; f"

To do the reordering you have to define and invoke a shell function to manipulate the argument list if you want the rest of the arguments anywhere but at the end where Git's alias pasting puts them.
There's no need to translate the newlines, the shell's wordplitting treats whitespace runs as argument separators, and newlines are whitespace.
I expect someone who knows a duplicate for this question offhand will be along shortly to close it as a duplicate, that's fine.

Thank you both! The two answers (this and @tmaj) both do the trick, and I have not seen limitations. The answer by @tmaj looks more readable, and this one has more lore. I will accept the other answer, but both are good.

As for the possible duplicate: In the end it will be another entry point for people to find what they are looking for.
